# When to use a particular operand constraint in extended GCC inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm having a hard time understanding when to use a particular input operand constraint over another in extended GCC inline assembly.

For example:

```
int x = 42;
asm("movl %0, %%eax;"
    : /* no outputs */
    : "r"(x)
    : "%eax");
```

I know that `"r"` tells the compiler to use a register hold the value of `x`, but when would it be more appropriate to use `"g"` or `"m"`? Would using `"m"` break this code since I'm using a register destination; and would `"g"` be too "vague" of an operand constraint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A large part of which constraint you use is whether the type it describes will work in the instructions you have. In `mov %0, %%eax`, you can put a register, a memory reference, or an immediate operand in place of `%0`, and the assembler will accept it. So you can use `g` for the constraint.

If you had `mov %0, 4(%%esp)`, then you could not allow `%0` to be a memory reference, because `4(%%esp)` is a memory reference, and there is no form of the `mov` instruction that accepts two memory references. So you would need to use a constraint such as `r` to require `%0` to be a register.

(Note that this code by itself is useless. As soon as the `asm` is done, the compiler is free to use `%eax` for anything it wishes, so there is no reason to expect that `x` will remain in the register. Moving something to `%eax` can be useful only in a sequence of instructions that uses `%eax` before allowing the compiler to have control again.)

Comment: +1. It's also interesting that the 64-bit 'version' would have to use `"rme"` as a constraint, since a 64-bit immediate value can't be loaded with `movq`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `g` when possible?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: It gives the compiler flexibility. If you use `m` but the value is in a register from a recent calculation, then the compiler must store it to memory. Or if it is a compile-time constant, but you use `r`, then the compiler must put the value into a register, while `g` would let it use an immediate operand.